# Location Detection without using CoreLocation

Tags: ios, iphone, location, core-location

I want to get the location without connecting to Internet. In older phone we have an option of cell info display which will display the current tower location or area name. I want to access that Location info in my iPhone App.

my Question as below :

**1) Is there any way to find the current location other than using CoreLocation, like taking the Tower information from Sim or anything similar to this?**

**If it is available, Is Apple allowing us to determine the Location from any other source?**

Answer (score 0):

Core Location in iOS devices works using the GPS. 
You can get the current location from GPS when you are not connected to internet.
I think for better accuracy only you need to connect to internet.

Comment: Is there any way to get the location without using GPS?

Answer (score 0):

Just set `desiredAccuracy` in distance(in kilometers or meter) or use GPS.